# How can display only the non minimum queries and exclude the minimum query

Tags: mysql

I have a list of skill ratings

```
john - 6.2
lucy - 4.3
nikki - 5.7
selena - 7.1
```

I just want to exclude lucy as hers is the least rating and order the rest by descending order wrt rating, and i dont know the total number of people in the list, so the limit function is not gonna work.
Any help, *noob alert*

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the actual columns which your table has?

Comment: Can there be ties? What happens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries

First use the inner query to find out the minimum rating then exclude the rating

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE rating NOT IN (SELECT MIN(rating) 
                     FROM table)
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general answer than the accepted one would be to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to remove any number of highest or lowest ranking rows.  Then use another subquery to impose any ordering we want.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY rating
    LIMIT 1000000000 OFFSET 1   --skips the lowest rating, but
) t                             -- we could skip any number of ratings
ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

## Demo